# Get a java.lang.ClassCastException during using SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, classcastexception

I use `SharedPreferences` in my app to save small `Integer` data . But I get `ClassCastException` in this line .

```
int number = mySharedPref.getInt("numberOne",0);
```

Here is my code .

To store data .

```
mySharedPref=getSharedPreferences("MyPref",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySharedPref.edit();
            editor.putInt("numberOne",myInteger);
```

To get data

```
 mySharedPref = getSharedPreferences("MyPref",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int number= mySharedPref.getInt("numberOne",0);
    display(number);
```

Comment: can you post your exception. Full stacktrace of exception

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you have not committed the data stored in `SharedPreferences`.
So you should do a

```
editor.commit();
```

while storing the data.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention in my question that . I use this line of code ` int number = mySharedPref.getInt("numberOne",0);` in the `onStart()` method . So when I open the app it crash .

Comment: Oh,then you should move it to onCreate()

Comment: I want to save an integer so when I reopen my app , I can find it .

Comment: No problem.You can retrieve it in the oncreate of the splashscreen in your app.Move the shared pref code from onstart to oncreate and it will work

Comment: When I use `apply` It works , when using `commit ` it works too . And when I move my code from `onStaret()` to `onCreate()` it works . I want to know what was the case of this exception and what is the difference between using commit or apply ?

Comment: apply and commit is same,the only diff is on successful commit,it returns true,whereas apply does not return anything.            
 onCreate() is the place wehere we should initialise all the variables,create views and perform all other activities whose result should sustain until ondestroy.Hence we should write the fetching from shared pref in oncreate()

Comment: Thank you . I have another question , Have I should declare another `SharedPreference` to retrieve data ? or I can declare a global `SharedPreference` for set data and retrieve it ?

Comment: It is a good practice to avoid any kind of global data.Still,if the shared preference value needs to be accessed throughout the app,then global data can be preffered

Answer (score 1):

Try this

To Store data

```
public static void setInteger(Context context, String key, Integer Value) {

        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor sEdit = sharedPreferences.edit();
        sEdit.putInt(key, Value);
        sEdit.commit();

    }
```

To get data

```
public static Integer getInteger(Context context, String key) {
    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
          .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
       Integer value = sharedPreferences.getInt(key, 0);

      return value;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `commit()` method to save data changes in `SharedPreferences`. 
Here is the get data method

```
private void showData() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyFile", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int number = sharedPreferences.getInt("numberOne", 0);
    display(number);
}
```

Here is get savemethod

```
private void saveData(int value) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyFile", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("numberOne", value);
    editor.commit();
}
```